# How can I re-export with CJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I re-export modules in CJS? What would be the CJS equivalent to the following ES6 code?

```
export * from './lib/setAttribute.js'
```

Comment: Maybe `module.exports = require("./lib/setAttribute.js")`, not sure though

Comment: Your way sounds like just only re-export default only

Comment: @NickParsons your solution worked! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do exactly the same way that `tsc` currently does as it compiles our code back to `commonjs`:

```js
var __createBinding = function(o, m, k, k2) {
    if (k2 === undefined) k2 = k;
    Object.defineProperty(o, k2, { enumerable: true, get: function() { return m[k]; } });
};

var __exportStar = function(m, exports) {
    for (var p in m) if (p !== "default" && !exports.hasOwnProperty(p)) __createBinding(exports, m, p);
};

__exportStar(require("./lib/setAttribute.js"), exports);
```